# Googlemaps - TypeError: directions() got multiple values for keyword argument 'mode'

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would kindly like a little help with this issue I am having my distance matrix code. Below is the piece of code:

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='my google API KEY')

now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions('29.6849782', '-95.3991907',
                                     '30.2228447', '-97.74735720000001',
                                     mode="driving",
                                     avoid="ferries",
                                     optimize_waypoints = True,
                                     departure_time=now)
```

I keep getting the above-mentioned 'TypeError' which I shall be glad for your assistance to help fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout the definition of the function and pay close attention to arguments order: [docs](https://python-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gmaps.html#gmaps.directions.Directions.directions).

Fixed code should look like this:

```
directions_result = gmaps.directions(('29.6849782', '-95.3991907'),
                                     ('30.2228447', '-97.74735720000001'),
                                     mode="driving",
                                     avoid="ferries",
                                     optimize_waypoints = True,
                                     departure_time=now)
```

Note parenthesis around coordinates.

Comment: Pleasure to help :)